# Angular ng-class not updating after ng-change is fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: It seems my issue is more complex than the simple typo in the code below. I have 3rd party components interacting and raising change events on the inputs which angular is picking up when I don't want it to. The problem is somewhere in there. I will try to find a simple fiddle and update the question if I manage it.

I have a pair of inputs, which have an ng-model and share an ng-change function. The ng-change sets a boolean value in the controller which is supposed to update the class(es) on the inputs through an ng-class directive. However the first of the two inputs never seems to get any updates to it's class. Here is a simplified version:

View:

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <input type="text" ng-class="{ 'invalid': firstInvalid }" ng-model="firstValue" ng-change="doOnChange()"></input>      
    <input type="text" ng-class="{ 'invalid': secondInvalid }" ng-model="secondValue" ng-change="doOnChange()"></input>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.firstInvalid = false;
  $scope.secondInvalid = false;
  $scope.firstValue = '';
  $scope.secondValue = '';

  $scope.doOnChange = function () {
      console.log('change fired');
      $scope.firstInValid = !$scope.firstInvalid;
      $scope.secondInvalid = !$scope.secondInvalid;
  };

};
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/Samih/pen/ZGXQPJ

Notice how typing in either input, the second input updates with the class just as I would expect, however the first never gets the 'invalid' class.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Typo: `firstInValid` in `doOnChange` should be `firstInvalid`

Comment: ffs. Thank you @iliacholy . I will take a look back at my original code as it isn't working there either and I combed it multiple times for typos.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code for typos:

This line

```
 $scope.firstInValid = !$scope.firstInvalid;
```

should be

```
 $scope.firstInvalid = !$scope.firstInvalid;
```

It should be `$scope.firstInvalid`, not `$scope.firstInValid`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me :
Just edited 'firstInvalid'.

View:

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <input type="text" ng-class="{ 'invalid': firstInvalid }" ng-model="firstValue" ng-change="doOnChange()"></input>      
    <input type="text" ng-class="{ 'invalid': secondInvalid }" ng-model="secondValue" ng-change="doOnChange()"></input>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.firstInvalid = false;
  $scope.secondInvalid = false;
  $scope.firstValue = '';
  $scope.secondValue = '';

  $scope.doOnChange = function () {
      console.log('change fired');
      $scope.firstInvalid = !$scope.firstInvalid;
      $scope.secondInvalid = !$scope.secondInvalid;
  };

};
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/vikashverma/pen/BNwKmQ